# В цикле запись HashMap строк из Сканера

Tags: java

Сделать в цикле запись в HashMap строк из Сканера,
пока пользователь не введет q.
Ключем записи будет текущая дата, значение - текст из сканера.
Проблемма в том что записуется только первая строка.

```
HashMap<String, Records> hm = new HashMap<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "windows-1251");
Records rc = new Records(sc.nextLine());
String date = new Date().toString();
do {
        hm.put(date, rc);

} while (!sc.nextLine().equals("q"));
sc.close();
for (HashMap.Entry<String, Records> item : hm.entrySet()) {
    System.out.printf(
            "Key: %s  Value: %s \n", item.getKey(), item.getValue());
}
```

Comment: В `HashMap` ключи уникальны и каждому ключу соответствует одно значение. Так как `date` при всех вызовах `put` одинаково, новое значение `rc` просто перезаписывает старое, записанное на предыдущей итерации.

Comment: +1 за слово "записуется".

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Не совсем, хотя и это тоже. Тогда была бы последняя строка. `while (!sc.nextLine().equals("q"));` Тут вообще создается только один объект `Records`.

Comment: @Igor Да, происходит запись только первой строки

Comment: @EvgeniyRadion Сколько штук `Records` создает Ваш код?

Comment: @Igor и еще если я напишу  `hm.put(Date.from(Instant.EPOCH), rc);` то выводит время 1970 года и опять же только первую запись

Comment: @Igor не совсем понял вас )

Comment: @EvgeniyRadion Смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    while (true) {
       String s = sc.nextLine();
       if (s.equals("q"))
         break;
       hm.put(new Date(), new Records(s));
    }
```

Comment: Да ваш вариант работает, а можно ли как то с вами связаться ?) есть еще пару вопросов)

Comment: @EvgeniyRadion Пожалуйста. Со мной можно связаться на StackOverflow :).

Comment: я думал мб скайп телеграмм или что то подобное )